# React fetch new data before render. Problems with componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs

I am sure even sure if I am doing this right, but I'd appreciate corrections as I am new to React...

So basicly, i'm trying to look for "post._links['wp:featuredmedia'][0].href", if that exists it will give me a new api url for me to fetch. And I want this new data before rendering my component.

So I tried by the following code. However I got the error "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');

// Dumb component
var x = 0;

export default class Post extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            featured: null,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const { post } = this.props;

        var Fimgurl = post._links['wp:featuredmedia'][0].href;

        if(Fimgurl != null){
            fetch(Fimgurl).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                this.setState({featured : data});
            }).catch(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }

    }

    createMarkup(html) {
        return {
            __html: html
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { post } = this.props;
        x++;

        if(x % 2 != 0){
            return (
                <div className="blog-post col-sm-7">
                    <div class="thumbnail"><img src=""/></div>
                    <h2 className="blog-post-title">{post.title.rendered}</h2>
                    <p className="blog-post-meta">{post.date} <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(post.content.rendered)} />
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="blog-post col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h2 className="blog-post-title">{post.title.rendered}</h2>
                    <p className="blog-post-meta">{post.date} <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(post.content.rendered)} />
                </div>

            );
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I want this done in the component is because I am looping out tons of posts, and each posts may not have the "post._links['wp:featuredmedia'][0].href" that gives me a new fetch url, so what I basicly want done is.

If current post have post._links['wp:featuredmedia'][0].href, then fetch from that string returned, then send the new json data to the render function so I can print it out....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your promise callbacks `this` does not refer to component instance. You should bind your callback functions or use arrow functions which uses lexical scoping (ES6 syntax):

```
fetch(Fimgurl).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
}).then((data) => {
    this.setState({featured : data});
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me solve that error.. However now I got a new one:
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" and "Error: findComponentRoot(..., .0.2.0.0.0.$23): Unable to find element."

Comment: @Codehiker probably `post._links['wp:featuredmedia']` is undefined. You should check it.

Comment: Sorry for going out of topic, it's probably because not all of the posts looped has the ['wp:featuredmedia'] in the json result. Is there any way to check if it exists and ignore if it doesnt?

Comment: @Codehiker sure you can check it in a simple condition like `if (post._links['wp:featuredmedia']) { ...`. It will pass if expression inside is truthy. Since you expect it to be an object/array is should work just fine

Comment: `var Fimgurl = post._links['wp:featuredmedia'] && post._links['wp:featuredmedia'][0].href;`

Comment: ^ `Fimgurl` will be the value or `undefined` if `post._links['wp:featuredmedia']` is not defined.